# React js shows error while showing object

Tags: reactjs, video-reactjs

I got an error when i go to console.log this object...in reactjs

Json object
`{"title":"Rtv","length":-1,"params":{"tvg-logo":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/41/Rtv_bangladesh.PNG/120px-Rtv_bangladesh.PNG","group-title":"America"},"file":"https://example.m3u8"}`

Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tvg-logo' of undefined

(anonymous function)

src/App.js:88

85 |
86 | return (
87 | items.map((data,key)=>{

> 88 | console.log(data['params']['tvg-logo'])
> | ^ 89 | const {title,params} = data;
> 90 | return(
> 91 | View compiled

Comment: Please ask your question much more clear.

Comment: please check again is it good now ?

Comment: the object `data['params']` is not defined.

Comment: i already declare this object but params have an another object name tvg-logo this tvg-logo object shows type error

Comment: I also use data['params']['tvg-logo']

Comment: @TomerAlmog any idea?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show? Are you sure that all item objects in the `items` array has the `params` key defined?

Comment: @FahadAli, this can happen when the data fetch after the component mounts. So when the console.log runs initially, that data params are not set. [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is best for scenarios like this.

Comment: I can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to see why the error is occurring in the small piece of code you have provided but to avoid this error you can use the conditional chaining discussed above; see example below.

```
console.log(data?.params?.tvg-logo)
```

This will return nothing if it fails anywhere along the object path.